# How to use react-swipe as a component?

Tags: reactjs

How can I use `react-swipe` as a component in my ReactJS app:
https://www.npmjs.org/package/react-swipe

I can get the example working from the `react-swipe` NPM page, but when try something like below it doesn't work:

NOTE: If I use `{React.DOM.div(null, carousel)}` instead of `<carousel />` it works. How can I get this working using JSX ? I can't figure out the equivalent JSX.

```
var App = React.createClass({
   render: function() {
      return (
         <div>

            <carousel />

         </div>
      );
  } 
}); 

React.renderComponent((
   <App />
), document.body);
```

Answer (score 3):

With fresh eyes and the blog post below I realized `carousel` is not a React Component, it's just JavaScript. I was assuming Swipe() returned a ReactJS component. This works:

```
<div>{carousel}</div>
```

This blog helped me figure this out:
https://www.packtpub.com/books/content/using-reactjs-without-jsx

Can also do this:

```
 this.carousel = (
      <Swipe continuous={false}>
        <div>
          <MyPrizesPane1 />
        </div>
        <div>
          <MyPrizeOne />
        </div>
      </Swipe>
    );
```